# Prove that $f:V \times V\to V$ $f(v,w)=v+w$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, metric-spaces, continuity

Let $V$ be a vector space with a metric $d$.Prove that  if $d(v+w,w+z)=d(v,w)$ for all $v,w,z \in V$ then $f:V \times V\to V$ $f(v,w)=v+w$ is continuous

Let $\epsilon>0$ and let $(v_0,w_0)\in V\times V$ arbitrary I need to prove $\exists \delta>0$ such that $d_{V\times V}((v,w),(v_0,w_0))<\delta$ implies that $d_V(f(v,w),f(v_0,w_0))<\epsilon$

I know the metric in $V$ but what would be the metric in $V\times V$?

Any comments suggestions or ideas would be highly appreciated

Comment: The metric in $V$ could be the sum of the distances between corresponding components, like the $\ell^1$ norm.

Comment: you can create different metrics in $V\times V$ e.g. you can take the supremum of both metrices or you could add them. you could even use the pythagoras to get a metric.

Comment: oh and I'm not sure about the metric ... but if you had a norm and V had finite dimension, you could take what ever you want because all norms are equivalent on finate dimension vectorspaces